# css3 linear-gradient background-image not working in opera 11.11

Tags: css, opera, linear-gradients

Opera 11.10 Ubuntu 10.04 64 Bit : WORKING

Opera 11.11 Windows 7 64 Bit : NOT WORKING

```
background-color: #D22027;
background-image:         linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your gradient code is wrong its not a image

```
background:         linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
background:      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
```

now they work for me in safari,crome,opera,opera next,IE and firefox.
and add these for compatibility

```
/* Chrome before 10,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
/* IE10 */
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #D22027, #444444);
```

and you can use 
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
for quick creation of high compatible gradients and/or for learning.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in using gradients in `background-image`. Check [css3please](http://www.css3please.com)